# Creating an outbound call center software in asterisk

Tags: voip, asterisk, call

I an outbound call centre as i know the server calls a person and connect the call to the executive.Executive via headphone attached to a system directly talk to the person means there is only one call from server to a person and executive doesn`t require a cellphone.
I am working in asterisk and want to make a similar system.
I have tried outbound calls in asterisk,and as far as i have done for outbound call server first calls the person and then to the executive and merge it so there are 2 calls and also in this case i cannot talk from server to person directly with headphones like call centre 
**Is it possible in asterisk?**if so what are the requirements for that apart from asterisk
and how to code dialplan with that
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialler-like applications are most complex dialplans for asterisk you can imagine.

You have be asterisk guru to do it form scratch.

If you are not guru, use already writed code like http://vicidial.org